How to set Render Selection in iterm2 latest version?
iterm2 has recently released its latest version 3.5, and one of the features is this

Add "Render Selection", which replaces a chunk
of selected text with a natively rendered view.
For example, JSON gets pretty-printed and syntax
highlighted. Rendered selections have the option
of scrolling horizontally to make navigating
logs easier. They are searchable. Over 150
different languages are supported for syntax
highlighting. Markdown gets special treatment
and displays its rendered format.

But I didn't find where to set it and I don't know how to turn it on
I can't find where to turn this on in the settings page of the profile


Select a text that you want to render
Edit -> Render Selection or use hotkey on Mac Command + Option + E

